# Array_push returning numbers of items or A last item with number

Tags: php, arrays

PHP - I am trying to push items into an array by using `array_push`.But it returns number of items in it.Not an array

```
$items = array();

$item1 = 'hello';
$item2 = 'hola';

$items = array_push($items, $item1, $item2);
print_r($items);
```

How can I get The $item as an array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between array\_push() and $array\[\] =](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232766/difference-between-array-push-and-array)

Comment: This is [a link to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) <-- the first place that you should look.

Answer (score 0):

[`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) returns the number of items in the array so don't assign `array_push` to $items and it should work as intended

```
$items = array();

$item1 = 'hello';
$item2 = 'hola';

array_push($items, $item1, $item2); // removed "$items =" from this line 
print_r($items);
```

Essentially your example was adding the elements to `$items` then overwriting it with count($items) due to `array_push`'s return value